# jQuery Bootstrap: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide')')

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I want to manually close a bootstrap modal view after the ajax request has been finished.
I call `jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide');` within the callback,

```
function(){                                       
   jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

but the modal view doesn't get hidden. I double-checked that I include jQuery before Bootstrap, so the problem can't be there.

I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide')')
```

The modal looks like this:

```
   <!-- Modal -->
<div aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="modalInviteFlatmateLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal hide fade in" id="myModal">
    <form id="add-flatmate-form" action="/flatmates/show" method="post">    
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
        <h3 id="modalInviteFlatmateLabel">Invite Flatmate</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            Enter the mail address of your flatmate you want to invite.
        </p><br />
        <input placeholder="E-Mail" class="input-block-level" name="AddFlatmateForm[email]" id="AddFlatmateForm_email" type="text" />    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="yt0" value="Invite" id="yt0" />        <!--<button class="btn btn-primary">Invite</button>-->
    </div>
    </form>
</div><!--#myModal-->
```

Additional information:

- jQuery version: 1.9.1,
- Bootstrap version: 2.3.2

Any ideas?

Comment: version of modal used?

Comment: can you check what is returned by `jQuery('#myModal').data('bs.modal')`

Comment: it returns 'undefined'

Comment: that means the modal seems to be destroyed.... can you share the code

Comment: there is no element with id `myModal`

Comment: would it not be `jQuery('#modalInviteFlatmate').modal('hide');` ?

Comment: where is the associated javascript that hides the modal

Comment: now what is returned by `jQuery('#myModal').data('bs.modal')`

Comment: still returns 'undefined'...and i posted the whole callback function above

Answer (score 0):

it's late but i hope this helps. 
Make sure you're including the jQuery library before your custom script, and that there are no errors in the Net tab of Firebug (make sure jQuery actually gets loaded). 
Test your javascript code in firebug and when ready to add to your actual code you can call it as anounymous function:

```
(function ($) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
     //your code
     ('# id of the modal element to close ').modal('hide')
   });
//your code
}(jQuery));
```

You can check this video [link to tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_G2kHiqU60), i think they have a good expose of debugging process.